# How can I define a header exclusive to the title page?

Tags: formatting

I'm very new to Latex and I'm having trouble making a title page. My university wants us to use a specific format for the title page to deliver our projects, so I'm trying to recreate it in Latex so I can use it as many times I want. This is the template they gave us:

[image: Title bar template]

It shouldn't be too hard to implement, but I'm not really achieving it. This is the code I got so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Variables
\newcommand{\numerotrabajo}{1}
\newcommand{\tema}{Sistemas}
\newcommand{\ejercicio}{Placeholder}

% Packages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{Test}
\title{Trabajo Práctico/Teórico N° \numerotrabajo\\Tema: \tema\\\ejercicio}
\maketitle

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ l r }
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Grupo X} \\
    \hline
    REDACTED & REDACTED \\
    REDACTED & REDACTED \\
    REDACTED & REDACTED \\
    REDACTED & REDACTED \\
    REDACTED & REDACTED \\
    REDACTED & REDACTED \\
    \vspace{250px}
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{ l l l l }
    Fecha Presentación & \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_ & Calificación & \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_ \\
    Fecha Devolución & \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_ & Firma Profesor & \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

And it produces this pdf:

[image]

As you can see I'm using the fancy header package to try to get that text at the top left that you can see in the template. It's not working for some reason. I would also need to make the "placeholder" text a bit smaller, and I would need a better way to show those lines at the very bottom of the page that should theoretically be used to be completed by hand.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `titlepage` environment is switching the pagestyle to `plain`; which is why `fancyhdr` isn't working for you. However, you can redefine the plain style with the `\fancypagestyle` command.

For "Placeholder", the text is already "huge", so you can ironically make it smaller with `\Large` or `\large`.

For the lines you could use `\underline` filled with arbitrary spacing commands, or `\rule`.

Here is a version with some more changes you may or may not want to use. It would certainly be possible to match the template even closer still with some additional packages, but given some of the choices you've made, I'm not sure you even want that. But feel free to ask if you'd like to, e.g., lower the title more, make the table in the middle more like the one in the template, and so on.

```
\documentclass{article}


% Variables
\newcommand{\numerotrabajo}{1}
\newcommand{\tema}{Sistemas}
\newcommand{\ejercicio}{\Large\bfseries Placeholder}

% Packages
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}% change margins
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tgheros} % a font more like the template

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}% clear everything
    \fancyhead[L]{\sffamily\itshape UTN -- Regional Buenos Aires\\
                          Análisis de Sistermas -- 2005\\
                          Curso K2002}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\title{Trabajo Práctico/Teórico N° \numerotrabajo\\Tema: \tema\\[2ex]\ejercicio}
\author{}\date{}
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\sffamily% switch to sans serif font like template

\maketitle

\begin{center}

\vfill

\begin{tabular}{l r}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Grupo X} \\
    \hline
    REDACTED & REDACTED \\
    REDACTED & REDACTED \\
    REDACTED & REDACTED \\
    REDACTED & REDACTED \\
    REDACTED & REDACTED \\
    REDACTED & REDACTED 
\end{tabular}

\vfill

\begin{tabular}{ l l l l }
    Fecha Presentación & \underline{\hspace*{1.3in}} & Calificación & \underline{\hspace*{1.3in}} \\[2ex]% add a bit more space
    Fecha Devolución & \underline{\hspace*{1.3in}} & Firma Profesor & \underline{\hspace*{1.3in}} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect for my needs! Only a question, what do the `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` and `\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}` commands do? I can understand everything else.

Comment: By default the fancyhdr package adds horizontal lines between the text and the header and footer (the "head rule" and "foot rule"). These commands remove those lines by setting them to a zero width. See, e.g., [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Headers_and_footers) near the bottom of the page.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks.